# 2 videos on webpage, one works perfectly, second plays audio but has no video

Tags: html, html5-video, zurb-foundation

I am trying to have to videos on a web page. One of them works fine, the second plays the audio but doesn't display any video. (I am using chrome, if that helps) I am using foundation too.

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-8 large-centered column teaserCon">
        
        <h2>traIlers</h2>
     
    <video class="videoTeaser">
     <source src="videos/Strutton_Taylor_FinalVideoTeaser.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="videos/Strutton_Taylor_FinalVideoTeaser.webm" type="video/webm"/>
        <source src="videos/Strutton_Taylor_FinalVideoTeaser.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
    </video>
    
    <div class="controlsTeaser">
     <button type="button" class="play-pauseTeaser button">&#9658;</button>
        <input type="range" class="seek-barTeaser" value="0">
        <button type="button" class="muteTeaser button">Mute</button>
        <input type="range" class="volume-barTeaser" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
        <button type="button" class="full-screenTeaser button">Full Screen</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="small-12 large-8 large-centered column trailerCon">

    <video class="videoTrailer">
     <source src="videos/Strutton_Taylor_FinalVideo_30sec.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="videos/Strutton_Taylor_FinalVideo_30sec.webm" type="video/webm"/>
        <source src="videos/Strutton_Taylor_FinalVideo_30sec.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
    </video>
    
    <div class="controlsTrailer">
     <button type="button" class="play-pauseTrailer button">&#9658;</button>
        <input type="range" class="seek-barTrailer" value="0">
        <button type="button" class="muteTrailer button">Mute</button>
        <input type="range" class="volume-barTrailer" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
        <button type="button" class="full-screenTrailer button">Full Screen</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```